# Add a constructor to a boost::python vector_indexing_suite exposed class

Tags: boost-python

I'd like to add a constructor so I can do this (my bytes are in strings because I'm using python 2.6 and 2.7):

```
import myboostpymodule

d = 'serialised representation of a vector of some c++ objects'

vec = myboostpymodule.MyVectorType(d)
```

Where I overload the vector constructor to accept a string, which will contain serialised data, and MyVectorType is exposed with `boost::python::vector_indexing_suite`:

```
namespace bp = boost::python;
bp::class_< std::vector<SomeType> >("MyVectorType")
    .def(bp::vector_indexing_suite< std::vector<SomeType> >());
```

- Is it possible to do this without wrapping (via subclassing and boost::python::wrapper<...>) the vector to add a constructor?
- Can I tell boost python to use a static method (or a plain function) as the constructor?

It's important that I can create the vectors from python using the constructor (not some other function).

<sub>I'm actually doing this because I'd like to make python instances of my vectors pickleable, and all my c++ types already have well-defined serialisation (including `std::vector<...>`), so it seems sensible to use this to pickle whole vectors at once, instead of allowing python to pickle each element independently<sup>1</sup>.</sub>

<sub><sup>1</sup>and it seems likely to be a higher-performance solution</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think using `boost::python::wrapper` will help you, since you'll need to use the constructor.  I looked at `boost::python::vector_indexing_suite` definition and I think you can in fact define your own constructor.

There's a function in boost::python to specify your own named constructors.  It is usually used to implement factory functions that return `shared_ptr`, but look like regular constructors from python.  You can look at http://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/HowTo#named_constructors_.2BAC8_factories_.28as_Python_initializers.29 for an example of this.

If copying your list is not expensive, I think you can simply do this:

```
using boost::python;
typedef std::vector<SomeType> MyVectorType;

MyVectorType makeMyVector(std::string myString)
{
    return CreateMyVectorType(myString);
}


class_<MyVectorType>("MyVectorType")
    .def(vector_indexing_suite<MyVectorType>())
    .def("__init__", make_constructor(makeMyVector));
```

However, if copying is expensive, you should be able to combine it with the shared_ptr factory approach described in the link.

Comment: Thanks; turns out that `make_constructor(...)` requires something that returns a `shared_ptr`-like object in any case.